# python algorithm: how to efficiently find if two integer sets are intersected?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, mongodb

Given a set [2004, 2008], what is the fastest way to find if this set is intersected with other sets?

Actually I am dealing a problem with database, the table has 2 columns, one is the lower bound, the other one is the higher bound. The task is to find all the intersected rows with the given 2 tuple(like [2004,2008]).

I am using mongodb, is this intrinsically supported(I mean have keywords to do it).
I have large user base, so I want this task to be completed as fast as possible.

EDIT: To stat more clear, a database table contains following rows:

```
20 30
10 50
60 90
...
```

Given the input `(25 40)` range, I want to return the rows which represent a range, have intersection with the given range.

so return is: `(20 30),(10 50)`

Comment: It is unclear from the way you've stated this, if you have *pairs* of values each pair representing range, and you want to know if any pair interesects, or you have two large set of values to intersect.  Do you know anything about the size of the integers?

Comment: I don't know MongoDB at all, but you're basically looking for `SELECT * from the_table where not (lower_bound > 2008 or upper_bound < 2004)`. If it can't do that, it's not a database ;-p

Comment: @Steve Yes, actually this is the answer!! please write your comment into an answer and then I can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know MongoDB at all, but you're basically looking for

`SELECT * from the_table where not (lower_bound > 2008 or upper_bound < 2004)`.

Comment: Seems like `SELECT * from the_table where (lower_bound < 2008 and upper_bound > 2004)` would be slightly simpler and equivalent.

Comment: @martineau: should be `<=` to be equivalent to mine, but yes. It's just not the way I think of it.

Comment: i don't even understand why some one is giving points for a SQL  answer to NOSQL database question.It provides the algorithm though. mstearn's answer is the right one here.

Comment: @Gnu: me either, if you look at the comments you'll see the OP asked me to post it as an answer, I suppose it was the best available at the time. I guess he can handle the syntax, his problem was that he couldn't concisely characterise the property of range overlap. It's easy to see the equivalence between this answer and mstearn's, via martineau's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming `low` and `high` are your bound fields:

```
db.ranges.find({'low': {'$lt': self.high}, 'high': {'$gt': self.low}})
```

Substitute `$lte` and `$gte` if you want your query to be inclusive rather than exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not support intersection. Perform intersection on the Python level using the intersection() API of sets.

Comment: This isn't using python sets, he's just using two integers to represent upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with lower bounds and upper bounds, you can just check bounds.

```
def intersects(this, others):
    upper, lower = this
    return [[u, l] for u, l in others 
            if (l < upper < u) or (l < lower < u)]
```

I don't know MongoDB but if you could implement that logic in the database, I can't help but think that it would be faster.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that tuples would be faster here than lists for storing upper and lower ranges as they can be significantly faster to construct.

Comment: looks like some bug here, a case is missing here, if the [lower, upper] is a superset of [u, l] :-)

Comment: @Bin chen - absolutely correct. Serves me right for posting in a hurry. It looks like MongoDB can do this natively though so this isn't a very good answer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mongodb query with a Javascript expression (assuming `lowerbounds` and `upperbounds` are the limits of the set being intersected):

```
f = function() { return this.lower <= upperbounds && this.upper >= lowerbounds; }
db.ranges.find(f);
```

This should handle all cases including when [this.lower, this.upper] is a superset or proper subset of [lowerbounad, upperbounds].

Comment: queries like that should always use the native query syntax and not javascript. javascript querys are much slower to execute and can't use indexes. See my answer for an example using the native syntax.